# React Native refresh the component after deleting a file from react-native-fs

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using react-native-fs to list and delete files in my app, I have listed all the files in one component and I have another component to show the file(Image Viewer), I want to delete the file on Image viewer and should redirect to list page after deleting a file, Deleting a file I am navigating to List component, but still I can see the deleted file on the list

```
deleteImageFile = () => {
  const fileName = this.state.fileName;
  const dirPicutures = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath;
  const filepath = `${dirPicutures}/${fileName}`;
  RNFS.exists(filepath)
  .then( (result) => {
      console.warn("file exists: ", result);

      if(result){
        return RNFS.unlink(filepath)
          .then(() => {
            console.warn('FILE DELETED');
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Gallery');

          })
          // `unlink` will throw an error, if the item to unlink does not exist
          .catch((err) => {
            console.warn(err.message);
          });
      }

    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.warn(err.message);
    });
  }
```

If there is file existing in the directory then File is deleting and if not I am getting file not exist message.

After successful deleting I am calling

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Gallery');
```

Gallery is main screen(List screen), the redirect also working but the deleted file is still present in the list.

Please help me on this.

Comment: How are you managing the state ? You are using redux ?

Comment: No I am using componentDidMount to read files from the `DocumentDirectoryPath` in a Array list like `this.state = {
            filesList : []
        }`

Comment: So you have to remove the deleted document from filesList table using splice or delete (hope your table is indexed)

Comment: I am deleting from FileSystem not from any table

Comment: I think you to delete from fileSystem and filesList in order to update the state.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [componentDidMount is not working when redirect to a screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53525357/componentdidmount-is-not-working-when-redirect-to-a-screen)

Comment: You can use react navigation event listeners to get this done. [This might be the solution you are looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53525574/5131689)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is simply that the application doesn't reflect the file system's real-time state.

There's not enough code here to tell, but `filesList` needs to be dynamically updated. This either means loading the file system contents into `filesList` each time the Gallery is presented, or removing the document from `filesList` upon a successful `RNFS.unlink(filepath)` event.